# Content security policy: blocked uri "about"

Tags: apache-2.4, http-headers

I am implementing `Content security policy` to my website headers. I currently have it on `report-only` setting for testing. My server is `Apache 2.4.7`.

After setting up some policies I keep seeing reports like this:

```
 "csp-report": {
        "document-uri": "http://www.example.com/page.html",
        "referrer": "",
        "violated-directive": "script-src 'self' http://www.google-analytics.com",
        "effective-directive": "script-src",
        "original-policy": "default-src 'self'; img-src *; report-uri  https://example.com/report",
        "blocked-uri": "about",
        "status-code": 200
    }
```

I don't know how to troubleshoot these reports. `Page.html` is contains static html and `Google analytics script`. What exactly is the uri `about` that is being blocked?

I have read Content security policy documentation but could not find anything that would explain this.

I cannot reproduce the error by accessing the same url with same browser type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After futher searching I was able to find this Stack Overflow post about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336860/why-would-i-get-a-csp-violation-for-the-blocked-uri-about

It turns out that this can be caused by browser addon that blocks urls by replacing them with `about:blank`.